# (?=) didn'work , i just change its position

Tags: javascript, regex

My regular expression did not execute correctly.

I get different results when I change its position.

"bbbWindows" is not what I wanted. Why not 'bbb2222'?

```
'Windowsbbb'.replace(/Windows(?=bbb)/, '2222') // 2222bbb
```

```
'bbbWindows'.replace(/(?=bbb)Windows/, '2222') // bbbWindows
```

Comment: ?= is a positive lookahead, and it captures nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Lookaheads (`(?=...)`) are zero-length assertions. They assert that the substring following that position in the original string must match the given pattern. In other words,

```
/Windows(?=bbb)/
```

Will match the substring `Windows` only if the substring immediately following the `s` also matches the pattern `bbb`. On the other hand,

```
/(?=bbb)Windows/
```

Will match the substring `Windows` only if the substring immediately following start position of the initial match also matches the pattern `bbb`—which is impossible, no string will ever match that.

The easiest way to get this pattern to work would be to use a regular 'in-line' group (`(...)`) and tweak your replacement string to insert this matched substring in the appropriate place (`$N`). For example:

```js
console.log('Windowsbbb'.replace(/Windows(bbb)/, '2222$1')) // 2222bbb
console.log('bbbWindows'.replace(/(bbb)Windows/, '$12222')) // bbb2222
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use positive lookbehind when the asserted pattern is behind the matching pattern:

```
'bbbWindows'.replace(/(?<=bbb)Windows/, '2222')
```

Comment: Lookbehinds are not supported in JavaScript.